# javascript callbacks - handle reading a file with fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, callback

For a project, I am using the net module to create a 'mini web framework'

I'm having a lot of trouble dealing with this one callback

```
var sendFile(path) {
  fs.readFile(path, config, this.handleRead.bind(this));
}
```

where readFile  is defined as:

```
var handleRead = function(contentType, data, err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);         //returns properly
  } else {
    console.log(data);        //returns properly
    console.log(contentType)  //returning undefined
}
```

So far this code works in the sense that I can catch errors and also write the data properly.

My question is : how do I send the contentType through the call back?

I've tried -

```
var sendFile(path) {
  var contentType = ContentType['the path type']
  fs.readFile(path, config, this.handleRead(contentType).bind(this));
}
```

But then this causes data and err to be undefined.

I'm quite new to js and am still confused about how to work with callbacks. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: So, what's `readFile`?  You've shown us `handleRead`, but not how it's called.

Comment: Hi @RocketHazmat  readFile is a method in module fs which I imported. handleRead is called within readFile as the third argument: `fs.readFile(path, config, this.handleRead.bind(this));`

Comment: That just passes a callback to the `readFile` method.  It doesn't show how/when it's called.  `this.handleRead.bind(this)` is just a function that needs to be ran/called at some point.

Comment: P.S. Your question says "where `readFile` is defined as", but then you show `handleRead` instead.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks I will edit the question. So what I'm building is a web framework that runs a server and handles requests. When the user tries to access a specific file, a response object is created and will call `sendFile(path_to_file)` which will call `handleRead` as a callback. Let me know if this doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Not knowing how `handleRead` is called (like with what parameters), you can try using `this.handleRead.bind(this, contentType)`.

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat ! that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) lets you do more than just set the "context" (`this` value of a function).  You can also "bind" arguments in the function.

Try:

```
function sendFile(path) {
  var contentType = ContentType['the path type']
  fs.readFile(path, config, this.handleRead.bind(this, contentType));
}
```

This will pass a callback with its context set to whatever `this` is and its 1st parameter set to `contentType`.  As long as this callback is called with `data` (and possibly `err`), then everything will work.